# JQuery to change background color of selected list item

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list and I would like to change the background color of each item when that item is selected(items in list are link tags) here is the JQuery code that I have so far.

```
$(".cat").click(function(){
    if ($('.cat').is(":selected")) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#1796cf");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
    }
});
```

HTML code is as follows:

```
<ul class="categories">
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">K-12</a></li>
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">Higher Education</a></li>
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">Recreation</a></li>
    <li class="cat"><a href="#">Community</a></li>
    <li class="cat" style="border:none"><a href="#">Faith Based</a></li>
</ul>
```

`.cat` is a class for each item in my unordered list. Problem is it is always running my else statement. What selector should I use to reference when the link is the one that is selected at the time? I tried using focuson() instead of click() but with other elements on the page this will not work the way I want it to.

Comment: "The :selected selector works for <option> elements." https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/rmx5ykhs/

Comment: @Sushil this is close to what I want but it doesn't change the color back to original color when a new link is clicked

Comment: @K8K try this then http://jsfiddle.net/rmx5ykhs/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1 - Minimal change**

```
$(".cat").click(function(){
    if ($(this).css("background-color") === "#333333") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#1796cf");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#333333");
    }

});
```

**Explanation** - "li" element does not have selected property,hence your code was not working. You can simply check the background-color property and toggle it.

**Approach 2 - Some what more change but cleaner code**

You can also simplify your code.

Update your script to

```
 $('.cat').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('background_selected');
    });
```

Add this in your css

```
.cat {
  background-color : #333333;
}

.background_selected {
  background-color : #1796cf;
}
```

With the above, you will have all the li's having background of #333333. And click event toggles the another class which overrides the background-color property to #1796cf. The only thing you need to make sure is .background_selected style should be after .cat style in your css file.

I hope both the approaches are clear.

**New Requirement - Select Only One element at a time.**

```
$('.cat').on('click', function(){
    $('.cat').removeClass('background_selected');
    $(this).addClass('background_selected');
});
```

Please note, this will do nothing if you click on selected element. However, if you need to toggle the class on selected element too and I want to unselect it on click, then you will need following code.

```
$('.cat').on('click', function(){
    var isAlreadySelected = $(this).hasClass('background_selected');
    $('.cat').removeClass('background_selected');
    if(!isAlreadySelected) {
        $(this).addClass('background_selected');
    }  
});
```

Comment: The second approach almost works the way I need it to...now I just need to get it to change back to original color when a new link is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want one one element with selected background at a time?

Comment: yes! that is exactly what I want. lol I just can't figure out how to do it lol

Comment: @K8K - I have updated the answers covering 2 scenarios. Hope that helps you.